# MySQL result multiple arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i.e : i have 2 tables

1. Product ( `id`, `name` )
2. Photo ( `id`, `name`, `photo_id` )

And I need to get result in `array` like this:

```
array(
 'id' => 1,
 'name' => product,
 'photos' => array(
      array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'photo1')
      array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'photo2')
  )
}
```

Is it possible in PHP using clear *SQL*?

I know that is possible to get 2 arrays and connect it but I have many records and I dont want to wase time to quering.

Comment: Try using nested queries maybe? You need to provide more information. Your table structure with some sample data along with the query that you've tried so far.

Comment: what did you try so far? show us your current code please

Comment: Why you are having id as well photo_id in your photo table `2 Photo ( id, name, photo_id )` just use product_id_fk instead of  photo_id and your are done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a foreign_key in your photo table "product_id".

Then create a method getPhotos() in your Product class with will collect all photos for your product.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in PHP using clear SQL?

Not in a single SQL call. With a single call, this is the closest you can get:

```
array(
 'id' => 1,
 'name' => product,
 'photo_id' => 1,
 'photo_name' => 'photo1')
),
array(
 'id' => 1,
 'name' => product,
 'photo_id' => 2,
 'photo_name' => 'photo2')
)
```

Your only choice for the format you want is to run queries separately or to combine them into the data structure you want.

Comment: Hi, all thank you for many answers. In my first post I have make mistake. In Photo table I Have product_id NOT photo_id ... pfff.

So if I will use that query "SELECT * FORM product p LEFT JOIN photo ph ON p.id = ph.product_id GROUP BY p.id" I return only one photo for product. So how I have to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is not possible with SQL. SQL is based on the relational model which is a 1-Normal-Form data model. That means, the result relation is also flat (no nested relations in a relation).

However, there are good frameworks which generate intermediary models in your corresponding target language (e.g. Python, Java, ...) that circumvent the impression of a flat data model. Check for example Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/

Moo